# Property of an generic class with unspecified type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class `SomeClass` with two type parameters:

```
public class SomeClass<T, U>
    where T : IFoo
    where U : IBar
{
    public void SomeMethod(T t) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then I have another generic class  `SomeOtherClass` with one type parameter. In this class I want to have a property of `SomeClass`. For this property I only want to have that the first type parameter of `SomeClass` to match the type parameter of  `SomeOtherClass` and I don't care about the second type parameter. So what I want to do is something like

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T>
     where T : IFoo
{
     public SomeClass<T, U> Frob { get; set; }
}
```

but that clearly doesn't compile. Can this even be done?

Comment: `SomeClass` doesn't seem to need `U` as a type parameter at all. Can't you edit `SomeClass` to remove it?

Comment: Yeah what exactly are you trying to achieve here? And if you really don't care about the second type parameter (which should be something that implements `IBar` anyway, so you do care a little), why not `public SomeClass<T, IBar> { get; set; }`?

Comment: @Sweeper modifying `SomeClass` is unfortunately no option

Comment: Generics in C# are fundamentally all about types known at compile time. The compiler needs an actual type for `U`, somehow (you could make `Frob` a method `Frob<U>()` -- I know that's not what you're looking for, but it could at least be made to compile). This is essentially a duplicate of a wide range of questions we get that basically amount to trying to find a way around the fact that the compiler needs to know the type. It's like asking why you can't define `public void f(int x);` and call `f();`: because you said "don't let me do this without a parameter", so it won't.

Comment: As your code stands, just delete the type param `U` and the constraint. Of course, I suspect `SomeClass<T, U>` actually does something with `U` so, `SomeOtherClass` will need a `U` to pass to it.

Comment: What if you replace `SomeClass<T, U> Frob` by `IFoo Frob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SomeClass<T, U>
    where T : IFoo
    where U : IBar
{
    public void SomeMethod(T t) { /* ... */ }
}
```

First thing I noticed, is if you don't need 'U' I wouldnt constrain on U. It just muddies the implementation and will make things down the line more difficult.

The second point is I don't think you can have an implicitly implied generic property, however you can definitely do this with methods.

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T>
    where T : IFoo
{
    public SomeClass<T, U> Frob { get; set; }
}
```

becomes (using abstract classes to ignore implementation details)

```
public abstract class SomeOtherClass<T>
    where T : IFoo
{
    public abstract SomeClass<T, U> Frob<U>(U parameter);
}
```

And you will not need to specify the 'U' generic parameter unless there's an ambiguity. Whatever you pass as a parameter will imply 'U'.

If that doesn't suit your needs, the another thing I can think of would be to default the U generic through a subclass:

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T, U>
    where T : IFoo
    where U : IBar
{
    public SomeClass<T, U> Frob { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherClass<T> : SomeOtherClass<T, IBar>
    where T : IFoo
{
}
```

Otherwise an interface should suffice (which would probably be my suggestion is to default it at this level)...

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T>
    where T : IFoo
{
    public SomeClass<T, IBar> Frob { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think that this is possible is to define an implementation of `IBar` which does nothing and use that.

```
public class NullBar: IBar
{
   // whatever no-op implementation that makes sense
}

public class SomeOtherClass<T>
     where T : IFoo
{
     public SomeClass<T, NullBar> Frob { get; set; }
}
```